# Convert range of dates in narrative form to .xts dates

Tags: r, xts

I have a character string "April 20, 2020 - April 24, 2020" and would like to convert it to two separate strings.  There are two problems here: (1) recognizing that the narrative "April" is the 4th month, and (2) that there are two different dates in this string.

I have looked at the following, plus others, but don't see my answer:

```
[extract dates from date range][1],
[select a range of dates][2],
[convert dates to range][3]
```

I've also studied "parse" but that doesn't seem to be the answer.

Comment: May be you can split and convert both strings to date.  For recognising two dates in string you can search that string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something like this work ?

```
string <- "April 20, 2020 - April 24, 2020"
dates <- as.Date(strsplit(string, ' - ')[[1]], '%B %d, %Y')
dates
#[1] "2020-04-20" "2020-04-24"
```

Or with `lubridate::mdy` if you don't want to remember the formats.

```
dates <- lubridate::mdy(strsplit(string, ' - ')[[1]])
```

Note that this is locale-dependent, your locale should be English.

Comment: Yes, this works.  Thanks. I wasn't aware of "strsplit", but I have a couple of questions:  I recognize the hyphen in the single quote marks, but I don't see in the description of "strsplit" what is being called for here.  Also, I need help in interpreting the double brackets with the 1.

Comment: That is the `split` part in `strsplit` meaning on which pattern do we expect to split our string. `strsplit` returns a list so using `[[1]]` we make it a vector. This is same as using `unlist` i.e `unlist(strsplit(string, ' - '))`

Comment: Coffee's on me!

Answer (score 0):

We can use `anydate`

```
library(anytime)
anydate(strsplit(string, "\\s*-\\s*")[[1]])
#[1] "2020-04-20" "2020-04-24"
```

Comment: I wasn't aware of this package.  I'll take a closer look at it.  Thanks.